# Multidimensional Knapsack W[1]-hard when parameterized by dimension

Tags: parameterized-complexity

Under [Multidimensional knapsack STRONGLY NP-complete](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21865/multidimensional-knapsack-strongly-np-complete) it was discussed that the Multidimensional Knapsack problem is strongly NP-hard.

Within this discussion the question whether the problem is W[1]-hard when parameterized by dimension d was mentioned, but not finally answered. Is the problem solved?

And: Is there any known xp-algorithm for multidimensional knapsack w.r.t. parameter dimension?

Comment: Sure the problem is at least W[1]-hard (unless P=NP). Because Knapsak is already NP-Complete.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean for inputs where input numbers are encoded in unary?

Answer (score 1):

Kellerer et. al. showed in Knapsack Problems (Springer), that the Multidimensional Knapsack is W[1]-hard w.r.t. $k$ (the required profit), even if $d=2$ (dimension).

Albrecht et. al. (in "Knapsack Problems: A Parameterized Point of View") generalized the result to $d\ge 2$.

With either result, Multidimensional Knapsack is para-NP-hard with respect to $d$. Thus, it is unlikely that Multidimensional Knapsack is in the class XP w.r.t. the dimension $d$.